# .NET CORE: Startup AddControllers, can not convert Filter to System.type

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, model-view-controller, controller

I created a `IAuthenticationFilter` for a bearer authentication but the calls dont run the Filter. Right now im calling the Filter inside the controllers (what is not working) so I want to try it globaly via Startup.

Startup:

```
services.AddControllers(options =>
{
   options.Filters.Add(new BearerAuthenticationFilter()); //<- cannot convert from Bearer... to System.Type
});
```

Comment: Have you tried `options.Filters.Add<BearerAuthenticationFilter>();`

Comment: @SBFrancies also not working